# Write a curl request in R

Tags: r, curl

I have necessary data about parameters for curl request that i need. They all are in this json:

```
        {
            "name": "GET /tablesbyquery",
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disableBodyPruning": true
            },
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "bearer",
                    "bearer": [
                        {
                            "key": "token",
                            "value": "hnjP4YUFwoR0jhUy_q8jF99jK5WlQ", 
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "",
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "json"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://source.os-pub.com/tables/tablesbyquery?timePeriod=actual&sort=utdDate,asc&query=&isNotEmptyStatus=false&size=20&page=0&providerId=",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "source",
                        "os-pub",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "tables",
                        "tablesbyquery"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "timePeriod",
                            "value": "actual"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "sort",
                            "value": "utdDate,asc"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "query",
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "isNotEmptyStatus",
                            "value": "false"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "size",
                            "value": "20"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "page",
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "providerId",
                            "value": ""
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
```

How to write curl request in R to extract this data? I see that i need to use access token here, but which parameters must also be included? And where should i put this parameters in GET function from httr package?

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty with this kind of question is that the person who answers is unable to test their code. Of course, you shouldn't share your real authorisation code, but since the URL is password protected, I don't understand why you need to give a dummy URL, which would make this easier to answer.

I'll therefore need to stick my neck out here and show you *what I think should work* rather than *what I know to work*.

Assuming the server is returning json or html, the following code should store the text response to res_text which you can then parse as required.

```r
library(httr)

url      <- "http://source.os-pub.com/tables/tablesbyquery?"
query    <- paste0("timePeriod=actual&sort=utdDate,asc&query=",
                   "&isNotEmptyStatus=false&size=20&page=0&providerId=")
full_url <- paste0(url, query)
key      <- "hnjP4YUFwoR0jhUy_q8jF99jK5WlQ"

res      <- GET(full_url, add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", key)))

res_text <- content(res, "text")
```